# Disable Hadoop Symlinks on Windows

Tags: windows-7, hadoop

I'm running Hadoop 2.2.0 on Windows 7.
When I try to execute my job, Hadoop tries to create symlinks in the temp folder on my local file system. This is not working as I do not have the necessary privilege.

I read that older versions of Hadoop on Windows didn't support symlinks at all and were just copying the files instead.

So **the question is**: Is it possible to turn symlinks off with a flag and switch back to the old behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you  have an error like this "Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: No privilege to create symbolic links."

You don´t have **SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege** in **Windows** try. Try `mklink /d 1 2` if you have an error message  try this

```
1) Launch secpol.msc via Start or Start → Run.

2) Open Security Settings → Local Policies → User Rights Assignment.

3) In the list, find the "Create symbolic links" item, which represents SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege.

4) Double-click on the item and add yourself (or the whole Users group) to the list.
```

If the problem persist perhaps the problem is related to UAC, you must disable it.

Type “MsConfig” in Start Search to start System Configuration, then go to Tools tab, select Change UAC Settings, then click on Launch button.

I hope this may help you.